# Setting environment variable by fetch the value from an URL before unix services start

Tags: unix, systemd, upstart

I need to set an environment variable before my init system actually starts other services, These services are baked into an AMI and use environment variables to run commands. In my case init system can be either upstart or systemd.

For setting environment I need to fetch that value of environment from a URL and then set the system environment variables so that other services can access that value when they start.

Essentially, I need to know where how i can set these environment variables so that they run before systemd or upstart starts the services.

OS - Ubuntu(14.04 or 16.10) and The services are running on Amazon EC2.

Comment: might be better asking on askubuntu.com

Comment: may want to set the environment variable  then restart the services you need to pick up the change.

Comment: services are dynamically created and i don't have details of the service before starting the instance

Answer (score 0):

I you put your service into docker, than at start up command you can add curl for envs (or add it inside your app if ou are delveloper)

If you use kubernetiss,
you also you can add readiness probe, to check that envs is successfully fetched

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/